# How to work out length of a formatted string

Tags: c#, string, console

I'm wanting to display a message on the console window, as long as the message won't exceed the default 0-79 X width of the window.The code I have looks like:

```
int xRemaining = 80 - mRobot.CurrentPos.X;
string message = "ID{0:d} Facing {1:s} at ({2:d},{3:d}) home is({4:d},{5:d})";
string formatMessage = string.Format(message,mRobot.ID,mRobot.getDir.ToString()/*...*/;

if(mRobot.CurrentPos.Y < 24)
{
  if (xRemaining < formatMessage.Length)
    {
     Console.SetCursorPosition((mRobot.CurrentPos.X - xRemaining), mRobot.CurrentPos.Y+1); 
    }
  else
    {
     Console.SetCursorPosition(mRobot.CurrentPos.X, mRobot.CurrentPos.Y + 1);
    }
}

else
{
  if(xRemaining < formatMessage.Length)
  {
   Console.SetCursorPosition((mRobot.CurrentPos.X-xRemaining), mRobot.CurrentPos.Y-1);
  }
  else
   {
    Console.SetCursorPosition(mRobot.CurrentPos.X, mRobot.CurrentPos.Y-1);
   }
}
Console.Write(message,,mRobot.ID, mRobot.getDir.ToString(), mRobot.CurrentPos.X, mRobot.CurrentPos.Y,mRobot.Home.X,mRobot.Home.Y);
```

Edit:
Used string.Format, still seems to be running onto the next line though :/

Comment: Think about the X-coordinate you're setting. At the moment this uses `xRemaining` which is independent of the formatted string length. Presumably you want something like `mRobot.CurrentPos.X - formatMessage.Length`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks man. Stupid arithmetic error on my part.

Answer (score 1):

You can format message with `string.Format` method:

```
string message = "ID{0:d} Facing {1:s} at ({2:d,3:d}) home is({4:d,5:d})";
string formattedMessage = string.Format(message, mRobot.ID, mRobot.getDir.ToString(), /* ... */);
int msgLength = formattedMessage.Length;
```

Later on, you can just display it with:

```
Console.WriteLine(formattedMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the string before getting it's length. You are currently getting the length of the unformatted string. To do that you need to use the `string.Format` command:

```
string output = string.Format(message, .....);

....

if (xRemaining < output.Length)
{
    ....
}

....

Console.Write(output);
```